# collapse twenty twelve submenu in mobile version

Tags: menus, sub-menu, theme-twenty-twelve

In the twenty-twelve theme, the following code will collapse the sub-menu `ul/li` on the mobile version. The problem is that it also breaks the normal version of the menu. How can I use it only when the mobile menu comes in?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.main-navigation li ul').hide();
    $('.main-navigation li').has('ul').click(function() {
    $(this).children().toggle();
    });
});`
```

Comment: What's wrong with the native menu? Twentytwelve does this by default out of the box, why do you need jQuery?

Comment: maybe i was not clear in my description but twenty twelve doesn't collapse the sub-pages as this jquery does. please note, i don't mean collapse the entire menu into the menu button...i mean collapse only the voices that have sub-voices so that if you click on them they will expand and show the sub-pages...

Comment: @CL75 hi...any idea?

Comment: Do you have a visual? Or a working example from a different site? I'm not sure if I understand just what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @CL75 no i'm sorry, i only found the script...i try to explain again: the subpages must be collapsed in the parent page so that the mobile menu will be shortered. when you click on the parent page the menu expands itself and you will see the subpages link...